# Best & Easily Customizable Survey Application available in Appexchange

Tags: appexchange

Which is Best Survey Application in Appexchange, where results are stored in our Org itself so that if we require to apply Bussiness Logic to the responses we can write triggers on the received responses.
Free / Unmanaged Package is most prefered.

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty broad, and ultimately is a "personal preference" type question without a definitive answer. Everyone has their own personal preference and there will always be new apps coming to market.

Personally, my org uses ClickTools by CallidusCloud:
http://www.calliduscloud.com/clicktools/

However, as I said, "what is best" is always up to debate, you should do market research yourself, schedule demos with various providers to determine their level of integration and/or if they are native, and use your own judgement to make the best decision that fits your business need.

This question is opinion based/open ended, so don't be surprised if the community votes to close it - you can check out [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what makes a good question for our community.